# Deadlock of threads java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I am new to threads and has come up with a deadlock example.
I tried to reproduce a deadlock scenario but the code worked fine without any problem.

Please guide as to where i am wrong.
Below is the code snippet

```
package Practice;

public class Deadlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deadlock a = new Deadlock();
        Threadslock first = new Threadslock(a);
        Threadslock second = new Threadslock(a);
        first.setName("First");
        second.setName("Second");
        first.start();
        second.start();

    }

}

class Threadslock extends Thread
{
    Deadlock lock ;
    private String anotherLock = "";
    Threadslock(Deadlock lo)
    {
        lock = lo;
    }
    public void run()
    {

        if(getName().equals("First"))
        {
            synchronized(lock)
            {
                synchronized(anotherLock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep (2000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException r)
                    {

                    }
                System.out.println("First Thread");
                System.out.println("Next Step in First");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            synchronized(anotherLock)
            {
                synchronized(lock)
                {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep (2000);    
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }

                System.out.println("Second Thread");
                System.out.println("Next Step in Second");
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

The output is like this :

First Thread
Next Step in First

Second Thread
Next Step in Second

Comment: The "trick" to getting a deadlock is lock interleaving, so you should sleep between your two synchronized blocks, not inside both.

Comment: Not an answer but, Your code (and your habits) would be more object-oriented if you implemented the two different thread behaviors with two different `Runnable` instances instead one `run()` method that has a big `if` statement that decides which behavior to perform.

Comment: @jameslarge thanks for suggesting the behaviour .. i was just checking whether a deadlock was possible in the above case also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sean Bright suggested, you add sleep in wrong place.

What's more, you have two `anotherLock` instances in both thread, it will never deadlock since both Thread First and Second Thread can get its own `anotherLock`. So you must let two threads share the same anotherLock.

Please check the code below ,hope it helps.

```
public class Deadlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deadlock a = new Deadlock();
        String anotherLock = "";
        Threadslock first = new Threadslock(a,anotherLock);
        Threadslock second = new Threadslock(a,anotherLock);
        first.setName("First");
        second.setName("Second");
        first.start();
        second.start();

    }

}

class Threadslock extends Thread
{
    Deadlock lock ;
    String anotherLock;
    Threadslock(Deadlock lo, String anotherLock)
    {
        lock = lo;
        this.anotherLock = anotherLock;
    }
    public void run()
    {

        if(getName().equals("First"))
        {
            synchronized(lock)
            {
                System.out.println("First Thread");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                synchronized(anotherLock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep (2000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException r)
                    {

                    }
                System.out.println("Next Step in First");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            synchronized(anotherLock)
            {
                System.out.println("Second Thread");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                synchronized(lock)
                {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep (2000);    
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                System.out.println("Next Step in Second");
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both locks need to be shared in order to create a deadlock. Try this

```
package Practice;

public class Deadlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deadlock l1 = new Deadlock();
        Deadlock l2 = new Deadlock();
        Threadslock first = new Threadslock("First", l1, l2);
        Threadslock second = new Threadslock("Second", l2, l1);
        first.start();
        second.start();

    }

}

class Threadslock extends Thread
{
    Deadlock first;
    Deadlock second;
    String name;

    Threadslock(String name, Deadlock first, Deadlock second)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public void run()
    {

        synchronized(first)
            {
                try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep (2000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException r)
                    {

                    }
                synchronized(second)
                {

                System.out.println(name + " Thread");
                System.out.println("Next Step in " + name);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

EDIT: Added sleep between acquiring locks

Comment: Hello @pablochan , even this code gives the same output . also in my code i think both the locks are shared by the two threads. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I ran the code and there is a deadlock. Just copy and paste it.

Comment: @pablochan. Both of your threads have a instance of anotherLock. anotherLock is not shared in your code.

Comment: @Gearon: I'm not OP :P

Comment: @ShivamJr7Both of your threads have a instance of anotherLock. anotherLock is not shared in your code.